# MobileFirst- Security test for Desktop environment

Tags: security, ibm-mobilefirst

We are trying to validate the usage of MFP to develop our desktop web site. However, I'm trying to understand the security test for desktop environment.

MFP provides the ability to add the security test for the desktop in the application-descriptor.xml:

```
<desktopBrowser cacheManifest="no-use" securityTest="VALUE"/>.
```

My application is configured to use the following two security tests, one for Mobile and the other for Adapters:

**Mobile:**

```
<customSecurityTest name="BankingTestMobile">
            <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="2"/>
            <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="2"/>
            <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="2"/>
            <test mode="perSession" realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" step="1"/>
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" step="2"/>
            <test isInternalDeviceID="true" realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" step="2"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
```

**Adapter:**

```
<webSecurityTest name="BankingTest">
            <testUser realm="BankingRealm"/>
        </webSecurityTest>
```

**My Realm is:**

```
<realm loginModule="BankingLoginModule" name="BankingRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="MBCAuthenticationAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="MBCAuthenticationAdapter.onLogout"/>
        </realm>
```

- What is the security test needed to protect the desktop app?
- Is there a documentation clarifying this as I couldn't find any on the knowledge centre.

I have tried using the adapter security test for desktop, but the `init` call started to fail.

Server version: 7.1.0.00.20161006-0540

Comment: Why is your adapter protected with a `webSecurityTest`?

Comment: Is there any drawback on protecting the adapters with 'webSecurityTest"? What is the better approach!

Comment: Well web security test is for web applications. Just use your own custom security test

Answer (score 1):

The optional `securityTest` attribute of `desktopBrowser` works just like any other platform.

See https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/authentication-concepts/classic-security-model/#protectApp

It allows you to protect the entire application with a security test of your choice. Meaning as soon as someone connects to the MobileFirst server from this desktop app, the defined security test will be triggered.

It's up to you to choose. Or not put anything.

On a side note, keep in mind that the Desktop environment does not support OAuth, which means you cannot use `WLResourceRequest` nor Java Adapters.

Comment: Thank you Nathan for replying, I used the "webSecurityTest" in my desktop application as defined above. but the init calls stared to fail.